# how can I import json file in typescript

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I am using typescript and requirejs. For the most part the amd modules are generated beautifully. I am however stuck with loading using requirejs json or for that matter text plugin.

```
define(["json!sometextfile.json"], function(myJson)
```

How can I do this in typescript. I am using TS 1.6 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have understood your question, but I think you want to know how to call `require` directly without getting a compiler error... for example:

```
require(["json!sometextfile.json"], function(myJson) {

});
```

The quick fix for this is to supply a very open definition for the `require` function:

```
declare var require: any;

require(["json!sometextfile.json"], function(myJson) {

});
```

You can improve upon this crude fix by using the full [RequireJS type definition from the Definitely Typed project](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e22d333b16d87656e47595157b07e2f5c1499589/requirejs/require.d.ts).